# I cant push Docker image to AWS ecr

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to push a Docker image from Dockerfile built to AWS ECR but when run this command:

```
$ aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 477629773586.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

appears the error:

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the
> GetAuthorizationToken operation: User:
> arn:aws:iam::477629773586:user/albertosanmartin is not authorized to
> perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: * Error: Cannot
> perform an interactive login from a non TTY device

I have installed and configured those files:

~/.aws/configure:

```
[default]
...
[mrthink]
region = eu-west-1
output = json
```

~/.aws/credentials

```
[default]
...
[mrthink]
aws_access_key_id = ****
aws_secret_access_key = ****
```

Seems to the command api get other user "albertosanmartin"

Anybody could help me please ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your credentials configured under `mrthink` profile name in `~/.aws/credentials` you need to pass the `--profile`  param to the aws cli

```
$ aws  --profile mrthink ecr get-login-password \
--region eu-west-1 |\
docker login --username AWS \
--password-stdin 477629773586.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

The user `arn:aws:iam::477629773586:user/albertosanmartin` doesnt have access to `ECR`

You can double-check your credentials via [sts get-caller-identity](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html) call if they are which you want to use.